# AWS Glue Column Level access Control

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-glue, policy

How to give column level access to particular roles in Glue Catalog? I want to give Role_A permissions to only column_1 and column_2 of Table XYZ And, Role_B to give access to  all columns of Table XYZ.

Comment: did u resolve??

Answer (score 5):

AWS Glue offers fine grained access only for tables/databases [[1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/fine-grained-access-to-glue-resources.html). If you want users to restrict to only few columns then you have to use AWS Lake Formation. Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/lf-permissions-reference.html#perm-select) which has examples.

For example if you want to give access to only two columns prodcode and location then you can achieve it by doing as shown below:

```
aws lakeformation grant-permissions --principal DataLakePrincipalIdentifier=arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/datalake_user1 --permissions "SELECT"  --resource '{ "TableWithColumns": {"DatabaseName":"retail", "Name":"inventory", "ColumnNames": ["prodcode","location"]}}'
```